# Selector passing to jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function in which I want the selector that I am passing to do the enclosed processes. The functions are listed below:

```
function menuselector (id){
    $(id).css('background', 'url(../img/black_denim.png) repeat');
    $(id).css('color', '#FFF');

}
function menudeselector (id){
    $(id).css('background', 'none');
    $(id).css('color', '#CE0101');

}

menuselector('mgi');
```

`mgi` is an ID of a `div` tag

Comment: You can pass an object to [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/): `css({'background' : 'url(../img/black_denim.png) repeat', 'color' : '#fff'});` or you could chain the two together (and select only once): `.css('background','url(...) repeat').css('color', '#fff');` If you should need to use the same element more than once, though, *cache* it, storing it as a variable, and thereby save the time it takes to find the relevant element(s).

Answer (score 6):

Ids are targeted by using a hash before the id, the same as in CSS.

If you're passing

```
menuselector('mgi');
```

You will need to adjust it to make it a valid selector.

```
$('#' + id).css(...
```

or you can send the valid selector

```
menuselector('#mgi');
```

assuming you have an element with that id (you haven't shown that)

```
<div id="mgi">
```

**Aside**

You shouldn't keep selecting the element. You can either chain

```
$(id).css('background', 'none').css('color', '#CE0101');

// on new lines for readability if there are a lot of actions
$(id).css('background', 'none')
    .css('color', '#CE0101');
```

or use an object

```
$(id).css({background: 'none', color: '#CE0101'});
```

Answer (score 1):

`mgi` is not a valid selector. You should write:

```
menusector('#mgi');
```

or

```
menuselector('.mgi');
```

depending on whether you want to select an ID or a class.

You could use popnoodle's solution, if your function should only be applicable to IDs, although making it restrictive like that seems like poor generality.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass '#mgi' if it is an ID:

```
menuselector('#mgi');
```